# Oracle Alter Table using Execute Immediate Not behaving as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, alter-table

I have PLSQL block like below which add a dummy column , does an update and then drops and renames columns

```
BEGIN
NULL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH ADD (TEMP_745634_1 VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE))';
UPDATE TESTMISMATCH SET TEMP_745634_1=TO_CHAR(A);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH DROP COLUMN A';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH RENAME COLUMN TEMP_745634_1 TO A';
End;
```

The first execute immediate statement is successful but the following UPDATE statement on the newly created column fails with the below error

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 25:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TEMP_745634_1": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
```

But if I run the same without a plsql block ,all the statements are executed successfully, like below.

```
ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH ADD (TEMP_745634_1 VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE));
UPDATE TESTMISMATCH SET TEMP_745634_1=TO_CHAR(A);
ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH DROP COLUMN A;
ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH RENAME COLUMN TEMP_745634_1 TO A;
```

My initial suspicion is that with regard to PLSQL context and SQL context switch that happens between First "Execute Immediate" statement and Update statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Oracle has to compile the PL/SQL block before it can execute it.  When it tries to compile the block, it finds that `temp_745634_1` is not a valid column name and throws the error.  This happens before Oracle can even try to execute the individual statements including the `execute immediate`.

If you want to refer to the newly created column in the same PL/SQL block where you created it, you'd need to defer compilation to runtime.  In order to do that, you'd need to make the `update` statement use dynamic SQL.  So if you do `execute immediate 'update ...` the PL/SQL block would work.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and after the change suggested , the plsql block runs successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like changes you've made in the first step are not viewable until the block ended.

This will help you

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH ADD (TEMP_745634_1 VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE))';  
  execute immediate 'UPDATE TESTMISMATCH SET TEMP_745634_1=TO_CHAR(''A'')';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH DROP COLUMN A';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TESTMISMATCH RENAME COLUMN TEMP_745634_1 TO A';
End;
```